# Getting a compilation error for DBT compile

Tags: dbt

Trying to run DBT model as below

```
{{
    config(
        materialized="table",
        table_type="iceberg",
        format="parquet",
        partitioned_by=["bucket(a_id, 50)"],
        table_properties={"optimize_rewrite_delete_file_threshold": "2"},
    )
}}

select
    *
from {{ source("source", "table1") }} as a
left join
    {{ source("source", "table2") }} as ao
    on a.a_id = ao.ao_a_id
    and a.db_name = ao.db_name
left join
    {{ source("source", "table3") }} as aof
    on ao.ao_id = aof.aof_id
    and ao.db_name = aof.db_name
```

but it always fails with the same error :

```
Compilation Error
  Got nested tags: macro (started at 498) did not have a matching {{% endmacro %}} before a subsequent macro was found (started at 548)
```

cant find the line nos and the logs are not helpful as well? any ideas on how to get this to compile?

Comment: This is probably not an issue with the model you are trying to compile since dbt will compile ALL macros at compile time. Start by looking at the macros in your project since it seems like one of them is missing an {{% endmacro %}} statement.